# Docker could not find package.json files

Tags: node.js, docker

I am very new to docker and have been encountering this error consistently when trying to build a node container with angular as the framework.

I have a simple `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS build

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4200

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin$PATH

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "docker-start"]
```

and the error I receive upon running the following command

`docker build -t angular-frontend .`

is such

```
 => CACHED [2/5] RUN mkdir -p /app                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => CACHED [3/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [4/5] COPY . /app                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                                      0.7s
------
 > [5/5] RUN npm install:
0.717 npm ERR! code ENOENT
0.717 npm ERR! syscall open
0.718 npm ERR! path /app/package.json
0.718 npm ERR! errno -2
0.720 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
0.720 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
0.721 npm ERR! enoent
0.722
0.722 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
0.723 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-11-22T00_08_31_998Z-debug-0.log
```

any assistance with a brief explanation of the solution and where I was failing would be fantastic

Comment: Is there in fact a `package.json` in the current directory?

Comment: Using the command `WORKDIR /app` you set working directory for the `RUN` command to be `/app`. But after using the command `COPY . /app`, This means you are copying the source code inside /app/app. I think the right command should be `COPY . .`

Reference: [Link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)

Comment: @DavidMaze do I need to manually create one with `npm init` then?

Comment: @B-saalGiri I added Dave's suggestion and that worked, but it didn't actually make the directory I have `CACHED [2/5] RUN mkdir -p /app` in the responses, but no errors this time and it ran the file to completion so that's an improvement.